# Which is the most efficient city for loot admin?

Tags: diablo-iv

The recent updates to Diablo 4 mean there is lots of loot, like, lots and lots of loot. Often I find myself running between the Blacksmith, Occultist and Stash to go through all my items.

Which city has these vendors the closest to reduce the amount of downtime I spend sifting through my loot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some very rudimentary measuring using a straight line 'as the crow flies' measuring in Photoshop, which I believe is pixels.

**Cerrigar**
[image: Cerrigar]

**Gea Kul**
[image: Gea Kul]

**Ked Bardu**
[image: Ked Bardu]

**Kyovashad**
[image: Kyovashad]

**Zarbinzet**
[image: Zarbinzet]

From this very basic measure, **Cerrigar** should be the most efficient place to organise and sort loot.